# I need to figure out why this element is aligned differently in Chrome versus Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

If you open this http://jaminweb.com/YoutubePlaylist.html in Chrome, you'll see that the red X is perfectly aligned with the text box to the left of it. If you open it in IE, on the other hand, it is misaligned. I'm trying to figure out why that is. Any help greatly appreciated.

Relevant code:

**CSS**

```
div.videl
{
   width: 80%;
   margin: 0 auto;  
   background-color: #39275b;
   color: white;
   padding: 5px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

textarea.vidtxt
{
    resize: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
}

img.rembtn
{
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    border: 1px solid #B43535;
    padding: 0px;
}

img.rembtn:hover
{
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    border: 1px solid #B43535;
    padding: 0px;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="videl">
    <p><textarea class="vidtxt"></textarea><img class="rembtn" src="xicon.jpg" width=20 height=20></img></p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Not aligned in FF either, make the textarea and img inline-block and vertical-align it to middle

Comment: `</img>` is not a valid tag.  The `<img>` tag is not a container so it does not get a closing tag.  Depending on your `doctype`, it's just `<img>` or `<img/>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
img.rembtn {
    border: 1px solid #B43535;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 24px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 24px;
}

textarea.vidtxt {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    resize: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 200px;
}
```

By setting the vertical alignment to middle and making both items display inline-block should allow them to align perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You should set them to the same height, currently they are different, and also add `vertical-align: top;`